# Dotnet core 3.1 global routing rule

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I write a project in dotnet Core 3.1, and all my controllers have the same attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

I wonder if there is a way to white this rule somewhere on a global level, like `Startup.cs`

I searched in the microsoft documentation and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Take a look at [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: That is actually better, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controller like this and all other controllers must be inherit form this controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ApiBaseController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

Another controllers should be like this

```cs
public class UsersController : ApiBaseController
{
}
public class OrderController : ApiBaseController
{
}
```